# Cannot using SQLDataProvider if SET @VARIABLE from query

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

I have a lot of query in my Mysql Database. Thte query is like this adn working fine.

```
 SET @cleaning = 'cleaning';
        SET @one_bar = 'one bar';
        SET @test_periodic = 'test_periodic';
        SET @repairs = 'repair';

        SELECT ir.id, ir.no_surat, @cleaning as tagihan,tc.`level`, tc.cleaning as nominal FROM ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate re
        LEFT JOIN ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report ir
        ON re.inspection_id = ir.id
        INNER JOIN ydepotras_finance.tagihan_cleaning tc
        ON re.id = tc.repair_estimate_id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT ir.id, ir.no_surat,  @one_bar as tagihan, tob.`level`, tob.one_bar as nominal
            FROM ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate re
        LEFT JOIN ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report ir
        ON re.inspection_id = ir.id
        INNER JOIN ydepotras_finance.tagihan_one_bar tob
        ON re.id = tob.repair_estimate_id
        UNION ALL

        SELECT ir.id, ir.no_surat,  @test_periodic as tagihan,
                ttp.`level`, IFNULL(ttp.years2,ttp.years5)  as nominal
            FROM ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate re
        LEFT JOIN ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report ir
        ON re.inspection_id = ir.id
        INNER JOIN ydepotras_finance.tagihan_test_periodic ttp
        ON re.id = ttp.repair_estimate_id
        GROUP by ttp.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ir.id, ir.no_surat,  @repairs as tagihan,
                tr.`level`, tr.`repair` as nominal
            FROM ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate re
        LEFT JOIN ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report ir
        ON re.inspection_id = ir.id
        INNER JOIN ydepotras_finance.tagihan_repair tr
        ON re.id = tr.repair_estimate_id
        ORDER BY no_surat
```

Now Yii2 is turn on.
This query will be turn into $dataProvider  and then, it's so much complicated if using  ActiveRecord.

I prefer to use SQLDataProvider like this :

```
$query = 'The query from above'

 $dataProvider  = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $query,
        'totalCount' => 100,
    ]);

 return $dataProvider->getModels();
```

But it gives me :

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the fact you don'assign dinamically value to yours mysql var  you could use directly the values instead of var

```
    SELECT ir.id, ir.no_surat, 'cleaning' as tagihan,tc.`level`, tc.cleaning as nominal FROM ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate re
    LEFT JOIN ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report ir
    ON re.inspection_id = ir.id
    INNER JOIN ydepotras_finance.tagihan_cleaning tc
    ON re.id = tc.repair_estimate_id
```

Or use  binding param

```
  $params = [':cleaning' => 'cleaning];
  $sql= Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
          SELECT ir.id, ir.no_surat, :cleaning as tagihan,tc.`level`, tc.cleaning as nominal FROM ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate re
          LEFT JOIN ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report ir
          ON re.inspection_id = ir.id
          INNER JOIN ydepotras_finance.tagihan_cleaning tc
          ON re.id = tc.repair_estimate_id )
             ->bindValues($params);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Please, how to handle the search ?

Comment: In this link you can find some suggestion for filter (search) and order by an activeDataProvider ..

Comment: What link ? . Btw, Thanks

Comment: i'm sorry  .this link  . http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/